# Font size decrease intermittently after printing from IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, zooming, font-size

Running an installation of osCommerce 2.2RC2 (secured, but an upgrade is in the works) on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (64-bit) and my tester is running Windows 8.1 (not sure if 32-bit or 64-bit) and IE11. Nothing fancy with the CSS, and it is not a responsive design. While I know there are other places for osCommerce support, this would not seem to be specific to osC.

The tester is reporting an intermittent reduction of font size after closing the print dialogue box when printing the product info page, but haven't offered more info than that (i.e. Crtl-P, menu selection, etc).

I've been unable to find info any reports of this happening aside from user-side issues with the default zoom (Ctrl-0) for IE11 being set higher than 100%, but then I might not be using the right word combos in my searches.

Has anyone else encountered this? if so, can you point me in the right direction for info on how to resolve, or a known workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same exact problem with IE 11 and my own ASP.NET web forms applications. Have you found a resolution or any more information on this? I think this question may get more answers if posted on http://superuser.com/

Comment: It looks to be related to zoom level changing when Print dialog appears. Initially in my case it was at 125%. After Print dialog was closed it changed to 100% but IE status bar was still incorrectly showing 125%.

Comment: Oh my. I did find the cause for this, but forgot to post the reason, and I'd moved on, as the matter did not repeat itself.

Comment: oops. If memory serves, it was a user-side issue, possibly related to IE's zoom settings...